# ios6 can work in iphone4s or earlier?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, storyboard

I am newbie to iOS development and I have two questions. As these questions are short I am asking in same question.

1. I am creating iOS application for which I am using iOS6. Will the application will work in iPhone 4s or earlier versions OR iOS6 works only in iPhone 5?
2. Also Storyboard works in iPhone 4 and next version mobiles only? Is that storyboard don't work in iPhone 3G?

Comment: @Rob : Thanks for the answer.. Can you have this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS 6 works on iPhone 3GS or later. Storyboards require iOS 5 or later (which means those 3GS or later devices running iOS5 or later). Since the iPhone 3G only goes up to iOS 4.2.1, then you cannot use storyboards on it.

And, by the way, Xcode 4.5 cannot even produce iPhone 3G-compatible apps any more, since it cannot support iOS prior to 4.3 (nor does it support the iPhone 3G processor, the armv6, anymore).

Comment: will accept after 7 mins... I love SO, but hate this feature to wait...

Comment: can you take a look at my another [**question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775745/how-to-select-viewcontroller-based-on-selection-done)