# how to select viewcontroller based on selection done

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, tabbar

This question is related to [***this***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743777/show-all-tabs-with-scrolling-option-on-screen-there-should-be-only-4-tabs).

I am using [**KLHorizontalSelect**](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/klhorizontalselect) for showing tab bar with scroll option. I have dragged new 7 View Controller on storyboard. If I select Popular, popular view controller should get displayed.

[image: KLHorizontalSelect]

Any idea/ suggestions on how to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical example of view controller containment (where you want one view controller to present other view controllers). Navigation controllers and tab bar controllers are example of built in container controllers. But effective iOS 5, Apple opened up containment for the rest of us.

Please see:

- [Implementing a Container View Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81) in the *UIViewController Class Reference.*
- [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6) in the *View Controller Programming Guide.*
- [WWDC 2011 - Implementing UIViewController Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102)

By the way, buried in the *View Controller Programming Guide* is subtle note about those four containment methods:

- `addChildViewController:`
- `removeFromParentViewController`
- `willMoveToParentViewController:`
- `didMoveToParentViewController:`

There are some strange interplay here. I would have thought that we, as application developers, would either just do the `add...` and/or `remove...` and that iOS would take care of all of the notifications for us, or that we would have to take care of the `will...` and `did...` notifications ourselves. But it's actually half-and-half. So read [Adding and Removing a Child](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW13) very carefully.

Comment: thanks for the info.. I shall look into it and get back to you incase of any concerns